# SQL query count by week with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to write a trend report for the amount of standing scaffolds in the database by week.
I can get a count of scaffolds erected by week in the example below and also dismantles using the same query but this isn't what I need.

```
SELECT COUNT(scaffID) Erected, WeekStart
FROM 
(
 SELECT ScaffID, 
        dateadd(week, datediff(day,0,Erected) / 7, 0) AS WeekStart  
 FROM Scaffolds
) o
GROUP BY WeekStart
```

I can get my standing scaffolds from this by putting in a date but I want the standing scaffolds on every Friday say.

```
Declare @staticDate As DateTime
Set @staticDate = '2/1/2015'

Select COUNT(scaffID) As StandingScaffolds
from RequestInfo 
Where (    ErectDate<= @staticDate )
  And (    DismantleDate>= @staticDate
        or DismantleDate Is NULL
      )
```

This is driving me crazy so any help would be extremely appreciated.

Phil

Comment: So you have one criteria (erected) that works on the overall week and another criteria (dismantles) that works on dates?

Comment: Basically what I'm after is Erects minus dismantles which will give me standing scaffolds. I need this grouped weekly though for a report.

Comment: Is your dismantles calculated based on the WeekStartDate as well?

Comment: I'm going to have to choose a single day in the week to perform this I think. (say a Friday)  I could use the above standing scaffolds query but adjust to group by Fridays.  It all gets very confusing to me when there is more than 1 date involved.  I'm just writing what is in my head to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Ok. Using Friday, Can you calculate the Erects and dismantles in seperate queries?

Comment: If on the 2-1-2015 I had 23 standing scaffolds and before the following Friday 9-1-2015 6 more had been put up taking it to 29 but 3 had come down bringing it back down to 26 then I need the report to say 2-1-2015 23 standing scaffolds | 9-1-2015 26 standing scaffolds etc.

Comment: It's for report viewer so cant do it separately. Result is going to be used in a graph.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you something to start with..

```
DECLARE     
    @startDate date = '2015-01-01',
    @endDate date = '2015-01-28';

with myWeeks (myWeek) AS (
    select DATEPART(WEEK,@startDate) myWeek
    UNION ALL
    select myWeek + 1 from myWeeks
    where
        myWeek < DATEPART(WEEK,@endDate)
)
select 
    w,
    COUNT(s.Erected) standingScaffolds
from myWeeks w
left join Scaffolds s on
    w.myWeek between DATEPART(WEEK,s.Erected) and DATEPART(WEEK,s.Dismantled)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to generate a date table for this (=table with one row for each day). You can then join that with this table to get the calculations quite easily.

```
select d.date, count(s.scaffID)
from date d, scaffolds s
where s.erected <= d.date and
(dismantled>= d.date or dismantled is NULL) and
d.date >= @stardate and
d.date <= enddate
group by d.date
```

Hopefully this is ok, can't test right now.

The date table is quite useful in other cases too, for example you can have local holidays there.

Comment: I'll give it a go in the morning.  Thanks for all the great responses!